# snipe-it with XAMPP

Tags: xampp, preflight

I have configured snipe-it following https://snipe-it.readme.io/docs/configuration and I don't seem to get pre-flight to run/launch and there is no instructions on snipe-it website unless I have missed it. I tried to use URL (http://localhost/setup) that I setup in the .env file but it says "This site can not be reached". I also tried IP but no luck. Any one out there have any idea what configuration file I need to check and how to launch it?  Thank you all

Comment: How do you try to see preflight requests without reaching the site? Have you even started your webserver?

Comment: Yes webserver is running - I started it from XAMPP control panel. localhost by itself takes me to XAMPP dashbord/welcome